# How to make a folder in the location of a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a batch script for which I have a script that is giving me a frustrating error. The location the batch file is being excecuted from is 
C:\Users####\Desktop\Sp2\Sp2.bat. I want the file to prompt the user if it wants to make a batch file. I got that down. I used the code

```
echo Would you like to create a directory to output the files to?
set /p mkdir=[Y/N]
if %mkdir%==Y (
    goto :mkdir
 ) ELSE (
    goto :numset
)
```

This part works fine. Now here's where the problem arises:

```
:mkdir
echo Enter a name for your folder.
set /p foldername=
MD %~d0\%foldername%
goto :numset
```

I this keeps giving me the error "The syntax of this command is incorrect."Can anyone give me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`%~d0` gives you the drive only. To get drive and path, use `%~dp0`:

```
MD %~dp0%foldername%
```

The complete listing of `%~?0` is well hidden. See: `for /?`

Answer (score 0):

`%~d0` expands to a drive of the batchfile. Users don't have permission to create folders in the root of a drive. So it will never work.

Plus the path seperator is `\` not the switch character `/`.